# Receive messages from groups or channels using Telegram bot API

Tags: c#, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on an application that integrates with **Telegram** and I had the problem to find a way how to receive messages from groups using **Telegram Bot API**

My code so far for sending a message to a group or channel my bot already admin on it. any suggestions?

```
static async Task<Telegram.Bot.Types.Message> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    var Bot = new Telegram.Bot.Api("api_token");

    return await Bot.SendTextMessage("chatid","Hello");
}
```

Comment: can you please know me how can send message in the group on telegram but using c#? i want also need this so can you please give me some idea.

Answer (score 3):

By default, your bot can only see messages in `/command@YourBotName` format, or reply to its message.

To receive all messages, please goto [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather), and turn off [privacy mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode), then re-invite your bot to group.

`/setprivacy` — Set which messages your bot will receive when added to a group. With privacy mode disabled, the bot will receive all messages.

Comment: thanks for the information but how to implement it in my code?

Comment: @AdamKim This have nothing to do with programming, just setup via Telegram Messenger

Comment: i did it but i didn't received nothing

Comment: clearly irrelevant answer. Does it answers `get messages from channel/group` ?
It just answers `/setprivacy`.