# how to read user send message from telegram in bot added group using API in C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to read the "user send message" in "bot added group" dynamically [and I'm able to sending the dynamic messages after read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271355/how-to-use-telegram-api-in-c-sharp-to-send-a-message) document].

But see the below example image: I want to read user send msg "hi", red circled.
[image: I want to read user send msg hi read circle]

So is there any API to read that message and not using this [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method.

using this [getUpdates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates) method. I'm getting every message here

Like this [image: Message list]
(It more difficult to read and insert in Database)

And I have read [this](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) full document and also I read some questions [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751015/receive-messages-from-groups-or-channels-using-telegram-bot-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976849/how-can-i-read-message-of-particular-user-in-telegram-group-using-telegram-bot-i) and also I searched in the google but I didn't get the relevant answer for this question

Can anyone suggest me is this possible or not?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

use webhook

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot{my_bot_token}/setWebhook?url={url_to_send_updates_to}
```